# PHP XML feed assembler works for every feed except Twitter

Tags: php, xml, feed

I'm trying to retrieve feeds from a twitter search to display on various parts of the site. I modified this function to do this yet it works for every feed a try it on except twitter.

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);

    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "
        <li>
          <a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a>
        </li>";
        }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

I am after only the content of the various associative posts. Here is a sample call.

```
<?php getFeed("feed://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=berkshire+golf"); ?>
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's search API is just a simple HTTP request, so your URL should be `http://` and not `feed://` if you're using `file_get_contents`

Edit:

You're also using `.atom`, use rss instead:

`http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=berkshire+golf`

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/divethe1/public_html/golfbrowser.com/wp-content/themes/master/functions.php on line 539

Comment: @Robin you should be using the RSS feed, not the atom feed. See inline.